# curl 7.87.0 ignores --output argument

Tags: curl

When I call

```
curl --output quarto.deb -L $(curl https://quarto.org/docs/download/_prerelease.json | grep -oP "(?<=\"download_url\":\s\")https.*${ARCH}\.deb")
```

the output is

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 26098  100 26098    0     0  33576      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 33588
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 84.5M  100 84.5M    0     0   9.9M      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:-- 11.0M
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

Why is curl ignoring the `--output` argument? I get the same result if I use `-O` (capital O).

I remember using the same command a couple of months ago and not having this problem.

Comment: What is `$ARCH` when you run this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl https://quarto.org/docs/download/_prerelease.json | grep -oP "(?<=\"download_url\":\s\")https.*${ARCH}\.deb"
```

this returns two url and cause issue

Comment: Only if `$ARCH` is empty, or some expression that matches multiple URLs.